# Matrix representation of Slater-Koster parameters

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, tight-binding

I'm coding a program to calculate electronic bandstructures using the Slater-Koster formalism (I am aware that such programs exist already- this is a pedagogical exercise). I notice that the $p-p$ [hopping elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding) can be written as the $\alpha\beta$ component of the matrix

$$
\begin{equation}
V_{pp\sigma}\hat{1} + (V_{pp\sigma}-V_{pp\pi})\vec{\eta}\vec{\eta}
\end{equation}
$$

where $\hat{1}$ is the identity matrix, $\vec{\eta}=(\ell,m,n)$ is a vector of the direction cosines, and $\alpha,\beta$ are components of $\vec{\eta}$. Does anyone know if similar representations exist for higher-order orbitals; *i.e.* can the five $s-d$ hoppings be written as the components of some five-element vector?